# Getting cell indexpath on swipe gesture UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, swipe-gesture

I am doing swipe gesture on `UITableView` and want to know indexpath of cell on which my fingers are currently into i.e. swipe gestured performed from which cell.

I require `indexPath` as I have to show information for that selected cell..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 54, accepted):

So what you essentially need is to get the cell from swipe gesture on the table? Right.You dont need to know the `indexPath`. First define swipe on the `tableView` like so -

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *showExtrasSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSwipe:)];
showExtrasSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[tableView addGestureRecognizer:showExtrasSwipe];
[showExtrasSwipe release];
```

After this when the actual swipe happens you need to put handler to it. For that try this-

```
-(void)cellSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    UITableViewCell *swipedCell  = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];

    //Your own code...
}
```

So what we have done is first attach a `SwipeGestureRecognizer` to the `UITableView` (not the `UITableViewCell`). After that when the swipe occurs on the `UITableView`, I first get the co-ordinates of where the gesture occurred in the `UITableView`. Next, using this coordinates I get the `IndexPath` of the row of where swipe occurred in the `UITableView`. Finally using the `IndexPath` I get the `UITableViewCell`. Simple really..

**Note:** I have been asked this far too many times. So adding this explanation of why I used `SwipeGestureRecognizer` on the `UITableView` and not on each individual  `UITableViewCell`.

I could have attached `SwipeGestureRecognizer` to each `UITableViewCell`. I did not do that since I would have had to attach a separate `SwipeGestureRecognizer` for each cell. So If I had 1000 cells in my `UITableView` I would have had to create 1000 `SwipeGestureRecognizer` objects. This is not good. In my above approach I just create one `SwipeGestureRecognizer` and thats it.

Comment: of course it did. This particular piece of code has already seen millions of swipes !

Comment: I think you need to changed the pinchedIndexPath to swipedIndexPath

Comment: I assign this code in my tableview which is a implementation of the horizontal table view style (tableview within a tableview) but the swipe does not fire?  The did select cell works so I know I am putting code in for right table....but no joy?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement 'swipe to delete' (swipe in the horizontal direction), you do not need to re-invent the wheel. Simply uncomment the method `commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` in your `UITableViewController` delegate.

Answer (score -1):

Did you checked this source code? :
https://github.com/thermogl/TISwipeableTableView

That really might help you, this is a full implementation of a "swipeable" tableview...